# Putty saving not saving sessions under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE

Tags: windows, putty

Windows 10 and Putty v0.76 and 0.78. My Putty sessions are not being saved to the Registry. Basically the main key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham does not exist. Instead Putty is saving the sessions under HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1606980848-861567501-725345543-2127627\SOFTWARE\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions. Any ideas why?

Update from some comments:
I installed both v0.76 and 0.78 from the MSI installers downloaded from the Putty site ([https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest.html)).

- What am I asking? Why is Putty not creating the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham registry key?
- Where is Putty saving it's sessions? (Clearly not the registry in my case)
- What is the registry key for 0.78?

What does it matter where they are being stored? Because I want to restore all my saved session keys from another machine but these aren't being shown in Putty since they are stored under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham and Putty is clearly not using this registry key on my case.

Comment: PuTTY (0.78 or any older) stores the sessions exactly there: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions` – See  https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyB5P.png – I have no idea what can be wrong about your installation. PuTTY cannot be told to store the sessions anywhere else. – Maybe post some screenshots yourself as an evidence.

Comment: OK I figured something out, Putty is not not using HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions but it is saving the sessions under HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1606980848-861567501-725345543-2127627\SOFTWARE\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions. I will edit the question as well.

Comment: Does the SID exactly match the one shown by `whoami /user`, or is the last number different?

Answer (score 1):

> Why is Putty not creating the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham registry key?

It *is* creating that registry key... only for a different user ID.

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER` is a **link** to `HKEY_USERS\<SID>` – its target is dynamic and will always show the SID of the user that's executing the process. Two identical processes, run by different users, will see different contents of HKCU and the changes made by each user will be stored under the HKU subkey corresponding to that user's account SID. (Your own SID can be seen in `whoami /user`; notice that anything you create under HKCU\Software is immediately visible under HKU\<your_SID>\Software.)

In your case, the SID `S-1-5-21-1606980848-861567501-725345543-2127627` is a *domain* SID (lacking the final RID component identifying a specific user within that domain) and usually means the process is running under the `SYSTEM` account instead of your personal account.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. whoami showed that the user SID was the same (ie S-1-5-21-1606980848-861567501-725345543-2127627). I have waited a bit and I see now that HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham registry has now been created. I think this is an issue with roaming profiles as it looks like the link between HKEY_CURRENT_USER and HKEY_USERS\<SID> is not constant.

Comment: I also checked the Putty process was running under my user ID, not system or any other account.